# Swift Generics Generic parameter could not be inferred

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to create a protocol that has a function with generic parameters.

```
protocol APIRequest {
    static func fetchData<T: Codable>(completion: @escaping(T?, NetworkError?) -> Void)
}
```

then I have a struct that conforms the protocol

```
static func fetchData<Ztar: Codable>(completion: @escaping (Ztar?, NetworkError?) -> Void) {
        let url = URLConstructor.url(scheme: "https", host: "swapi.dev" , path: "/api")
        guard let url = url else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil, NetworkError.badResponse)
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let object = try decoder.decode(Ztar.self, from: data)
                completion(object, nil)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

but I'm not sure if that implementation of the type of the generic is correct because in my `ViewController` I'm receiving the error **Generic parameter 'Ztar' could not be inferred**

```
NetworkManager.fetchData { star, error in
            
}
```

Can someone explain What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to implement this correctly. What type is Ztar? How would the compiler know? You've written "`fetchData` will fetch some kind of data, out of all the infinitely possible kinds of data in the universe, and you, the compiler, should decode it." That's not possible.

Instead, the way this would generally be written is:

```
fetchData<T: Codable>(ofType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkError>) -> Void)
```

And then you would need to pass the type you expect as the first parameter:

```
fetchData(ofType: Record.self) { resultRecord in ... }
```

If you don't know what type Ztar is, how can the compiler?

(Note that you should almost never use `(T?, Error?)` as a type. That says "maybe T, maybe Error, maybe neither, maybe both." You almost always mean `Result<T, Error>` instead. That says "either T or Error.")

Comment: or simply `fetchData<T: Codable>(completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkError>) -> Void)` and when calling `fetchData { (result: Result<Record, NetworkError>) in ... }`

Comment: @Rob Napier  thanks for your response. So that's the main question everytime I need to let know the compiler what type is? and the type should always be in the implementation?

Comment: @Robert How would it be otherwise? Consider an arbitrary JSON object. How would you decode it to any possible type that could exist? If you don't know the type of the JSON, how could the compiler?

Comment: @LeoDabus That syntax is much more obnoxious to use. It's much better to include the type somewhere directly in the call, like in Decodable. You can add a `ofType: T.Type = T.self`, which is very nice as a shortcut when the type is obvious, but you shouldn't remove it entirely.

Comment: @RobNapier got it, makes sense if I don't know the type  the compiler neither. Thanks for your explanation